# How to insert user entered date in Postgresql using spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public void insertDate(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(date);
        String query = "insert into Calender values ( '"+ date + "')";
        jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    }
```

I have used postman to send json data

```
{
    "date":"2020-12-12"
}
```

I am getting error like this

```
 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "{
    "date":"2020-12-12"
}"
```

POJO Class

```
private String date;
```

What changes need to done in query??

Comment: which date format do you have in your DB?

Comment: @Nick I used this query => create table calender (date Date);

Comment: @Nick and when i click on view data it shows read only column. but values are inserting when i use insert query in database.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your rest controller?

Comment: ` @RestController
@RequestMapping("date")
@CrossOrigin("*")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DatePickerController {
 
 private DatePickerService datePickerService;
 @PostMapping
 public void insertDate(@RequestBody String date) {
  datePickerService.insertDate(date);
 }
}

Comment: As a note: **Never** use string concatenation with input to create SQL statements; this is exactly how SQL injection works. JdbcTemplate provides features for templated statements and parameters to fill in. (I believe it also supports `LocalDate`, which is what you really want here. Your problem is that you're passing the entire JSON input as a `String` instead of as some class with a property named `date`.)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I tried using LocalDate date , but how to accept jsondata int then? will you please answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the query but your RestController. You should write a separate class for your request.

Say `RequestDate.java`

```
class RequestDate {
    private String date;
}
```

And in your Rest Controller you will have to change your Request Body to map to RequestDate instead of String

```
@RequestBody RequestDate date
```

and when calling the service

```
datePickerService.insertDate(date.date)
```

Now the entire request body is being passed down and you are trying to insert the string 
"{
    "date":"2020-12-12"
}" into the table instead of "2020-12-12"

Comment: Yes I understood i am inserting json data into a date column. I hav already created a separate file DatePicker.java as  pojo class where private String date; i there. then  i tried date.date in daoImpl file in the query but i didnt work.please guide

Comment: String query = "insert into Calender values ( '"+ date.date + "')";
  jdbcTemplate.update(query); i am getting error is date couldnt be resolved

Comment: again i tried this also     LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(date);
  System.out.println(d); still gets an error ..parsing error